# Векторные иконки в версиях ниже 5-ой

Tags: java, android, vector

Использую в своём приложении векторные кнопки(social) но они используются от 5-ой версии и выше, и вот незадача, моё приложение использует устройства с 4.4.

Соответственно данные кнопки не видны в версиях ниже 5-ой, как можно решить данную проблемку?

Comment: У меня тоже такая проблема сейчас. Переконвертировал svg в xml drawable, но при запуске приложения на устройствах ниже андроид 5 выдаются ошибки типа в xml на какой-то строчке ошибка

Comment: магические [манипуляции по подключению](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html#vector-drawables-backward-solution) поддержки `VectorDrawable` на устройства ниже API21 вы проделали?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще векторные иконки в формате `vector-drawable` должны и на устройствах ниже 5 версии отображаться. Просто они будут автоматически конвертироваться в png. Можно использовать как написал @Vladimir Parfenov `app:srcCompat="..."`

Comment: В Materialdesignicons к примеру даже пишет следующее, при попытке скачать векторные иконки: Vector Drawable Viewer (5.0 API Level 21+). Как вариант использовать дополнительно иконки с таким же названием(bitmap)?

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите в xml задавать векторный ресурс, то используйте не `android:src="..."`, а `app:srcCompat="..."`.